# I can't install and uninstall software through the Ubuntu Software Center!

Tags: software-center

Every time I try to install or uninstall any program through the Ubuntu Software Center, I keep getting errors that I do not have permission to do that even when I am logged in as an administrator. What do I do? (When I first installed Ubuntu on my computer, it did not have the Software Center. I had to install it through the terminal with this command: `sudo apt-get install software-center`)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: The version of Ubuntu I'm using is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: In linux when logging in with password, it does not make you administrator.  You need to use your password to make changes to your system, as in installing software.  It should ask for your password to install/uninstall software.  Software-centre might be wonky also.

Comment: It never asked me to enter any password

Comment: Then software centre is wonky.  It should ask for password, right after hitting install button.  You did need to use password when you use sudo?  Would either try the other software installing programs in Ubuntu, like synaptic and/or delete software centre and install another one, you have choices.  16.04 will need to be upgraded soon(a couple of months).

Comment: I typed this into the terminal: `sudo software-center`. Then it asked me for my password, then it launched the program. Then I only can uninstall programs. It still does not let me to install programs.

Comment: As I said the program software centre is wonky, broken, buggy.  A delete and reinstall of software centre might help or change to another program.  When Ubuntu first started software centre, I found it too be so slow, that I installed app grid in it's place.  It does seem better in newer version of Ubuntu(20.04), but still had to go and install gnome software centre.

Comment: Thanks! I have uninstalled the Software center with App Grid.

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021. You may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.